# string pattern validation in html

Tags: javascript, html

I used to write a code for passing strings into an api. This stings must satisfy some pattern and then if it satisfies the pattern it has to call an api by clicking a button to store this strings.

passing string to database

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> 
<style> 
body{
  background: url("images/background.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
 }
```

```
<div class="data" >
   <h1>SignUp Here</h1>

        <form   method = "POST" >

        <p>Username</p>
        <input type="text" name="citycode" placeholder="Enter citycode"   id="citycode"  pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 6 or more characters">
        <p>Password</p>
         <input type="code2" name="countrycode" placeholder="Enter countrycode" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 6 or more characters" id="countrycode">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button> </br> </br> </br>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {
  var citycode, countrycode;
  city = document.getElementById('citycode').value;
  country = document.getElementById('countrycode').value;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "https://my api url";
  var sending = JSON.stringify({
    "citycode": city,
    "countrycode": country
  });
  xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
  xhttp.send(sending);
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      console.log("status success");
      alert(xhttp.responseText);
    }
  };
  //}
}

</script>


</html>
```

when I am clicking submit button, it is checking and showing the pattern matching result but data is passing in both valid and invalid cases.

can any one help me to fix this.

Comment: You declare the variables `citycode` and `countrycode`, but then assign to `city` and `country`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `myFunction()` in the submit button's `onclick` attribute. Form validation happens when the form is being submitted, which is after the `onclick` function returns. Do it in the form's `onsubmit` attribute.

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="myFunction(); return false;">
```

You should also use `return false;`, otherwise the form will be submitted normally, even though you've already sent the data using AJAX.

Comment: Can you please explain me in detail.

Comment: What did I leave out?